# Is it possible to point 2 virtual hosts with different domains and unique IP addresses to the same folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualization, hosts, domains

is it possible to point 2 virtual hosts with different domains and unique ip addresses to the same folder? If so should I be aware of anything? Also is it possible for each of those domains to have SSL certificates even though the are pointing to the same directory?

Sorry if I sound confused.

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to point 2 virtual hosts with different domains and unique ip addresses to the same folder?

Yes.

> Should I be aware of anything?

You should read up on [virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) in Apache.

> Also is it possible for each of those domains to have SSL certificates even though the are pointing to the same directory?

It depends. If they can use the same certificate, and that certificate is a wildcard certificate it's quite simple.

e.g. If you have a two domains `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` you could use a wildcard SSL certificate on `*.example.com` for both of them.

Otherwise, you'll have to try [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which is a bit more complicated. The browser support for this is still rather dismal. If you attempt this, then all Windows XP users will be unable to access your site using IE or Safari. More exceptions are detailed on the previously linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: Hi thank you for that. I was unsure of the SSL issue. So it sounds like I cannot installed an SSL for domain.com and a SSL for domain2.com? I must buy a multi-domain certificate then?

Comment: @Darren: It is almost always advisable to have separate SSL certificates for each domain name, and every SSL certificate must be on a distinct IP.

Comment: @Darren: You can have multiple SSL certs but they must be for different IP addresses.

Comment: Hi thanks guys, that is what I thought, as long as I have 2 unique IP addresses. Thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Should be entirely fine, the directory is unimportant with regard to that setup and it is not uncommon for the same codebase to be used for multiple sites.

If the output of the websites is exactly the same, then beware of Google marking you down for having duplicate content, if you care about SEO.

Also, if you use `.htaccess` files that perhaps use the `RewriteBase` instruction, be careful if the URL paths are not identical.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. The content will not be an issue because this is going to utilize a Magento multi store structure.